# Primes Between Triangular numbers and Legendre's Conjecture. Reference request

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, conjectures, prime-gaps

It is an unsolved problem if there is a prime between two consecutive triangular numbers. A positive answer to this problem would solve Legendre's Conjecture. What happens if we look beyond consecutive triangular numbers and instead ask if there is a prime number $q$ such that $q \in(T_n, T_{n+k})$ for some positive integer $k$. Obviously $k=1$ is the original statement. Are there any materials on this or has anyone solved a k such that the statement is true?

Note: this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/695772/is-there-a-prime-between-every-pair-of-consecutive-triangular-numbers).

Comment: The only case I know off the top of my head is the fairly obvious one: if you take $k$ to be $n$ (so, not constant) the claim is true. That's just because $T_{2n} > 2T_n$ and $(n, 2n)$ always includes a prime.

Comment: So you are suggesting consider $T_5$ which is $15$ and then looking at $T_{30}$ which $465$ and so there must be a prime between them - presumably you are using Bertrand's Postulate and then as you mentioned the fact that $T_{2n}>2T_n$?

Comment: No, I'm saying that there's a prime between $T_5 = 15$ and $T_{10} = 55$. Since $T_{2n} = 2n(2n + 1)/2 > 2n(n + 1)/2 = 2T_n$, Bertrand's postulate states that there's a prime in between.

Comment: Gotcha. So again with your example if we consider $T_{13}=91$ Then $T_{2n} =2*13*(2*13+1)/2 =351 =T_{26}>182$ so there is a prime in there.

Comment: Correct. I don't know if we can do it with a fixed $k $, though.

Comment: For fixed $k$, that would imply that for any positive $\epsilon$ and large enough $x$, the prime gap is $\lt x^{1/2+\epsilon}$. I think that is stronger than any known result.

Answer (score 1):

This is to big for a comment but - I write the positive numbers starting at $1$ in a triangle:$$\mathbb{N}_\triangle = \begin{matrix}
    &&&&&21&\ldots         \\
    &&&&15&20&\ldots       \\
    &&&10&14&19&\ldots     \\
    &&6&9&13&18&\ldots   \\
    &3&5&8&12&17&\ldots \\
    1&2&4&7&11&16&\ldots 
    \end{matrix}$$

In a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873164/locating-the-double-of-a-number-in-a-triangular-arrangement-of-the-integers) it was shown that if $x$ is in column $n$ then the double of $x$ can be found in the $d_n(x)^{th}$ column where $$d_n(x)=\Bigg\lceil{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 16x} \above 1.5pt 2}\Bigg\rceil$$ we can then use [Betrand's Postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) to show that there is a prime $q$ in between the columns $[n,d_n(x)]$. In particular if $T_n$ is the n$^{th}$ triangular number then there is a prime between $T_n$ and $T_{d_n(x)}$. So for example if $T_{13}=91$ then the double of $91$ is $182$ which is in column $$d_n(91)=\Bigg\lceil{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 16*91} \above 1.5pt 2}\Bigg\rceil =19$$ and $T_{19} = 190$. So there is a prime $q \in (T_{13},T_{19})$. Compare this to the comment above that gives a bound $k=2n$ and so gives us $T_{26}=351$.  I am certain $T_{d_n(x)} \leq T_{2n}$. I write out the intital  values of $d_n(x)$ for $n^{th}$ triangular number
$$ 2,3,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,18,\ldots$$ and this appears to be $$2(n-1)-\Bigg\lfloor(n-1)\sqrt{1 \above 1.5pt 3}\Bigg\rfloor$$ Compare to this sequence [A195129](https://oeis.org/A195129).